# How to recover "three axis camera control" widget?

Tags: 3d-view

I'm sure it's an easy question, but I'm not sure what this thing is called to even look up the answer.

I made a custom Layout workflow tab that better suits me, and created a new Layout.001 workflow tab to recover the original default layout. Layout.001 is missing this little three-axis view angle control, though--how do I get it back? It's not the nub of an arrow you can see on the upper right; that just summons the <kbd>N</kbd> menus. I personally prefer hotkey, but if you know how to recover it from menus, that would be great for completeness. Thanks!

(PS is it possible to rename the workflow tabs?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the object in question is the *Navigation Gizmo* and the toggle checkbox for it is under the *Gizmo* menu (highlighted below):

[image: NavTools]

Comment: I had simply hit the little "+" icon to create the workspace; nothing more. I think the layout came in without the widget by default. Thanks!
PS how did you resize the circles in your navigation widget? Edit > Preferences?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure what you mean by "resize" - I don't think I altered the default values at all. Maybe it's because I'm using 3.0 alpha?

Comment: That might be it. I thought you'd simply adjusted various UI elements. Looks snazzy. Thanks for answering! (Incidentally, do you know if it's possible to rename workflow tabs, e.g. Layout, Modeling, Layout.001?)

Comment: Double click the name

Comment: Thanks! I swear I tried that before x)